# Reason to not enable encryption on Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've noticed that Azure blob storage now has the option to encrypt your data at rest.

There's no financial cost to this as far as I can tell and there's no indication/documentation anywhere that states how much of a performance impact this will have on access speeds (If any).

My question is, is there a good reason to ***not*** turn it on in most cases?

I imagine that if you've got a scenario where every millisecond counts and security isn't an issue (Such as for public containers perhaps), then maybe you might not want to, but otherwise it sounds like a nice feature to turn on for free (No such thing as a free lunch, but I can't find evidence of a downside beyond speculation).

Comment: No I don't think there is a good reason not to - it's part of Microsoft's trust strategy - gives the data owner more confidence, removes another reason for people not to move data to Azure storage.

Comment: This should be moved to the security stack exchange

Comment: @CtrlDot I disagree. The question is not about the need for the feature itself (encryption), it's more about it's technical implications, like performance or other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable SSE for your blobs, there is no distinguishable impact on performance.

The only case where you might think twice about it is if the storage account only holds VHD files that are being used by VMs. It is better to use Azure Disk Encryption for VMs, which uses DMCrypt for Linux VMs and Bitlocker for Windows VMs. Bitlocker, for example, will go back and encrypt everything on the disk.

SSE only encrypts newly written data. This means if you have a storage account with 100 GB of data and you enable SSE, that 100 GB of data is not encrypted unless you copy it to another container or something like that so it will encrypt it. However, any blobs added to that storage account WILL be encrypted.